# I cant figure out the diffrence between following two syntaxes

Tags: php

```
while($rowForStateList  =   @mysql_fetch_array($resForStateList))

{
    $sid[$i]    =   $rowForStateList['state_auto_id'];

    $sname[$i]  =   $rowForStateList['state_name'];

    $spid[$i]   =   $rowForStateList['country_auto_id'];

    $i++;
}
```

AND

```
while($rowForStateList  =   mysql_fetch_array($resForStateList))

{
    $sid[$i]    =   $rowForStateList['state_auto_id'];

    $sname[$i]  =   $rowForStateList['state_name'];

    $spid[$i]   =   $rowForStateList['country_auto_id'];

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: The `@` sign is the difference. There is a question: What does this symbol means here on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `@mysql_fetch_array` in first code sample fetches the array **suppressing** any errors, while `mysql_fetch_array` do the same but **not suppressing errors**. Actually, the second one is more correct way.

The evil of using `@` is in that it comlicates debugging a lot. With this suppression, in case of error you'll end up with empty arrays, so it will look just like query used to get `$resForStateList` have returned empty result. But, you actually might have broken query, refused database connection and whatever else. And with `@` **you will never know that something goes wrong**.

So, don't use `@`. Instead, use error [handling functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php). And the best way is to check if something could cause error, e.g. `mysql_query` returns false in case of any error, so you might want to check it like

```
$result = nysql_query("qwerty");
if (!$result){
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: +1 for saying that using @ is incorrect.  You might want to add why though.

Comment: So, would somebody explain why this post is downvoted? Am I wrong? :)

Comment: @JOHN, you got me.  Mine got downvoted too, I think someone got their panties in a twist over posts that said or implied that the @ operator wasn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the former will mask any errors that occur in `mysql_fetch_array()`, making debugging more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The @ in the first version basically means "If this function triggers an error, just hide it, don't log or display it".

Don't ever use the @ error suppression operator!  Not only does it make for a debugging nightmare, but it also harms application performance.  Use error_reporting, log_errors and display_errors to set proper error message behaviour instead.

Comment: And someone appears to have downvoted this?  Could you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the @ operator in this case. mysql_fetch_array will only throw an error if the resource is not valid. You should have checked this before, after you got this resource.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the error reporting.
If you set a @ before mysql_fetch_array, any errors will be ignored.
[see php errorcontrol](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0):

the only difference is that the `@` in front of the `mysql_fetch_array` in the first code will supress any error from being displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

the first one suppresses errors: http://davidwalsh.name/suppress-php-errors-warnings

Answer (score 0):

They are identical. The first `mysql_fetch_array()` will not produce error messages due to the suppression operator `@`.

Answer (score 0):

The first one will silently ignore any error. The second one will display any error or exceptions thrown the `mysql_fetch_array` (for example, connection problem). The magic comes from the `@` sign.

Answer (score 0):

`@mysql_fetch_array($resForStateList))`
doesn't show up any message in case of an error. 
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The @ is an operator thet suppresses errors. Your statement will not throw errors when the @ is added. You can read more here: http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2006/05/07/php-the-operator/

Answer (score 0):

When you prepend '@' to an expression, any error messages that might be generated will be ignored (ie. no error output will be generated). Anyway if the track_errors feature is enabled, any error message generated by the expression will be saved (and overwritten on each error) in the variable $php_errormsg.

Check [PHP Error Control](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) for more details.

Actually, I prefer to use expression widthout '@' and handle all exceptions with a function that log all message in a file with [error_log()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php). Something like:

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile=null, $errline=null, $errcontext=null) {
    error_log($errstr, 3, 'debug.log');
}

set_error_handler('error_handler', ERROR_REPORTING);
```